# A-frame limit cameras y distance

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

I have some code that restricts the camera movement in A-frame so when the camera moves 10 spaces away from the starting point, they are teleported back to the position 0, 1.6, 0. Currently, this works is the players x or y axis moves 10 spaces away from their starting point. How can I modify this so the player is only teleported back if **only** their y position moves 10 spaces from their starting point? Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('limit-my-distance', {
      init: function() {
        this.zero = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
      },
      tick: function() {
        if (this.el.object3D.position.distanceTo(this.zero) > 10) {
          this.el.object3D.position.set(0, 1.6, 0);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  <a-scene>
    <a-sphere position="0 2 -10"color="red"></a-sphere>
    <a-plane color="green" position="0 0 -5" rotation="-90 0 0" width="20" height="20"></a-plane>
    <a-camera limit-my-distance></a-camera>
    <a-sky color="#fff"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can even do something like this to not trap into walls at position 4 around you!
Here as well with camera movement settings WASD

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('limit-my-distance', {
      init: function() {
          // nothing here
      },
      tick: function() {
        // limit Z
        if (this.el.object3D.position.z > 3.8) {
          this.el.object3D.position.z = 3.8;
        }
        if (this.el.object3D.position.z < -3.8) {
          this.el.object3D.position.z = -3.8;
        }

        // limit X
        if (this.el.object3D.position.x > 3.8) {
          this.el.object3D.position.x = 3.8;
        }
        if (this.el.object3D.position.x < -3.8) {
          this.el.object3D.position.x = -3.8;
        }

      }
    });
</script>
<a-scene>
<a-sphere position="0 2 -10"color="red"></a-sphere>
<a-plane color="green" position="0 0 -5" rotation="-90 0 0" width="20" height="20"></a-plane>
<a-camera limit-my-distance look-controls wasd-controls="acceleration:10" position="0 1.6 0"></a-camera>
<a-sky color="#fff"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check only the `y` axis, then it's as simple as checking the difference of two numbers:

```
// distance = |y_position - y_start|
const y = this.el.object3D.position.y;
const distance = Math.abs(0 - y);
if (distance > 10) {// do your stuff}
```

Something like this:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('limit-my-distance', {
    tick: function() {
      if (Math.abs(this.el.object3D.position.y) > 3) {
        this.el.object3D.position.y = 2;
      }
    }
  });
  AFRAME.registerComponent("fall", {
    tick: function() {
      this.el.object3D.position.y -= 0.15
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-sphere position="0  2 -5" color="red" fall limit-my-distance></a-sphere>
  <a-plane color="green" position="0 0 -5" rotation="-90 0 0" width="20" height="20" material="wireframe: true"></a-plane>
  <a-camera></a-camera>
</a-scene>
```